# how to open fancybox from javascript.

Tags: javascript, fancybox

I have the following code in my cshtml file.

```
<div style="display:none">
<div id="EditFancy" class="fancybox-infobar">
//Some not relevant input fields. 
</div>
</div>
```

I'm trying to activate/show that fancybox from a javascript which is included at the top of the cshtml file.

However I'm able to activate/show it from a link within the same cshtml file. With the following code:

```
    <a href="#EditFancy" class="btnForm" id="btnForm">asd</a>
     <script type="text/javascript">
        $("#btnForm").fancybox();
    </script>
```

Help will be greatly appreciated.

Comment: So you have a chunk of code that you're running somewhere in the page and it works but it doesn't work when you put it at the top of the file? Why bother putting it at the top of the file?

Comment: @MikeC maintainability mostly

Comment: @KyleBecker That doesn't make sense. It's just as maintainable to put all of your scripts at the bottom of the page, which is what you should be doing anyway unless you have a very good reason not to.

Comment: I was a bit vague. The 'divs' is in the cshtml file, at the top.(before the include of the javascript file that is intended to show the fancybox). 

The problem is that I'm not able to show the fancybox from the 'external' javascript file. 

The workaround, as of now is to write the fancybox content inside the javascript, but that's not very pretty. I can provide more code, if that is helpful.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could create your own click handler using event-delegation that opens fancybox, for example:

```
$( "body" ).on( "click", "btnForm", function() {
  $.fancybox.open({ src: $(this).attr('href'), type : 'inline' });
});
```

Comment: Thanks! However I just found this:  jQuery.fancybox.open(jQuery('#btnForm')); btnForm being the id of the <a> tag used too open the fancybox.

Answer (score 1):

```
function viewproperty() {
    $.fancybox.open({
        src: "#propertyInfo",
    });
}
```

This code is for the latest version of facncybox.

Answer (score 0):

If you use jquery try to wrap the code with $(document).ready() function or use window.onload() javascript function

Comment: The function which is suppose to call for the fancybox is inside a $(document).ready() function.

Comment: Do u check if your script is loaded before the library load. Do you manage script section at view shared layout page? These consideration may help.

Comment: Yes, they where loaded. Turns out I should use jQuery.fancybox.open(jQuery('#btnForm')). Thanks for your help!

Answer (score 0):

Used jQuery.fancybox.open(jQuery('#btnForm')); to open the fancybox from the javascript.